# Container closing the instance

Tags: docker, containers, google-cloud-datalab

I'm a newbee to container and docker and I just found out that google datalab is a container.

So What I do now is to first ssh to the remote VM, then I run the

```
docker exec -ti <docker-container-id> bash
```

to open the container. Then I run my python script using python main.py

But I found that after running it, it will cause my datalab instance to stop. And also I'd love to run the main.py in the background as it takes a lot of time.

Any ideas of how to do it?

Comment: What is the base image that you are using?

Comment: http://e-lin.github.io/wiki/jekyll/update/2016/12/13/Running-Google-Cloud-Datalab.html might help